# JavaMail getText() method always returns null on HTML emails

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm using the JavaMail FAQ function [getText()](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) to get the main body of text of a specific email on an IMAP server. Here is the function getText():

```
            private String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException
    {

        if (p.isMimeType("text/*"))
            {
                String s = (String)p.getContent();
                textIsHTML = p.isMimeType("text/html");
                return s;
            }
        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative"))
            {
                //prefer html over plain text
                Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
                String text = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++)
                    {
                        Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                        if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain"))
                            {
                                if (text == null)
                                    {
                                        text = getText(bp);
                                    }
                                else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html"))
                                    {
                                        String s = getText(bp);
                                        if (s != null)
                                            {
                                                return s;
                                            }
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        return getText(bp);
                                    }
                            }
                        else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*"))
                            {
                                Multipart mp2 = (Multipart)p.getContent();
                                for (int j = 0; i > mp2.getCount(); i++)
                                    {
                                        String s2 = getText(mp2.getBodyPart(i));
                                        if (s2 != null)
                                            {
                                               return s2;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
        return null;
    }
```

This works fine for any email of plain text, however when I pass it any email with HTML content it returns null.

The debug from the IMAP session returns:

```
    611 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE (("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "BASE64" 3544 50 NIL NIL NIL NIL)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "BASE64" 10218 145 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "--boundary_4761316_0c192fe0-3967-48b0-9b2b-241c3dd04471") NIL NIL NIL))
```

The fetch itself contains lots of garbled characters. I'm not really sure why this is happening, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is the base64 encoding has you stumped, but you should post the full set of headers that you have in the mail, as well as the full mail body (trimming any long sections to something smaller for this post)

Comment: @rolfl yes, that is the problem I believe. The full IMAP debug is here [link](http://pastebin.com/EGRujix6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reformatted the code you broke it.  You inserted braces in the wrong places.